# Why does this load bearing stud not extend all the way to the floor?

Tags: framing

In the center of the below picture, I recently had a cable installer come out and they drilled a 1" hole (effectively cutting the stud) right through the middle of the stud with the electrical box on it! Since this is a load bearing wall, I'm trying to figure ways to repair that stud.

I can see that there is a sistered stud on the left of the damaged stud, but it doesn't extend all the way to the floor. What is the purpose of this stud? Can I fix the damaged stud by mending the sistered stud to extend all the way to the floor?

[image]

Comment: That stud is a runner to catch the exterior sheathing. You can see it's two different sheets at the bottom, that didn't quite make it. A 1" hole is fine. But they're all notched for that horizontal 2x4? Or is that just blocking?

Answer (score 1):

The load from the discontinuous stud is transferred to the adjacent stud through nails between the studs. (The other stud is also reinforced due to a notch for a light switch box or something.)

You should check this by counting the number of nails between the studs. They probably used 16d nails and each valued at about 106 lbs. of shear. (I’d expect about 5-6 nails.)

Comment: Really a not connected stud connects to some place some how? - but I say where I disagree!